# Java: My 2D array runs out of bounds 1 number less than it should every single time

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add a string to a 2d array, maze. It compiles, but when I run it it gives "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3" even though the dimensionY is set to 4.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\zarga\\OneDrive\\Documents\\HW\\CSIS139\\MazeSolver\\src\\maze.txt"));
    // now print out what the text file has in a for loop.

    for (String line : lines) 
    { 
        System.out.println(line); 
    }
    String line = lines.toString();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Dimensions: " + Dimensions1(lines) + " by " + Dimensions2(lines));
    System.out.println("Start position y: " + getEndCoordinateY(line));
    System.out.println("Start position x: " + getEndCoordinateX(line));
    char[][] mazeArray = new char[Dimensions1(lines)][Dimensions2(lines)];
    mazeArray = mazeCreator(lines, mazeArray );
}

//get first number in dimension
public static int Dimensions1(List<String> list)
{
    String firstLine = "";
    String stringList = list.toString();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        firstLine = firstLine + stringList.charAt(i);
    }
    int firstDim = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
    return firstDim;
}

//get second number in the dimension
public static int Dimensions2(List<String> list)
{
    String firstLine = "";
    String stringList = list.toString();
    for (int i = 5; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        firstLine = firstLine + stringList.charAt(i);
    }
    int secondDim = Integer.parseInt(firstLine);
    return secondDim;
}

//get ending coordinate Y position
public static int getEndCoordinateY (String list)
{
    String lastLine = "";
    String stringList = list;
    int startY = 0;
    int length = list.length();
    for(int i = length - 2; i > (length - 5); i--)
    {
        lastLine = stringList.charAt(i) + lastLine;
    }
    startY = Integer.parseInt(lastLine);
    return startY;
}

//get ending coordinate X position
public static int getEndCoordinateX (String list)
{
    String lastLine = "";
    String stringList = list;
    int startX = 0;
    int length = list.length();
    for(int i = length - 6; i > (stringList.length() - 9); i--)
    {
        lastLine = stringList.charAt(i) + lastLine;
    }
    startX = Integer.parseInt(lastLine);
    return startX;
}

//create the maze
public static char[][] mazeCreator (List<String> list, char maze[][])
{
    int dimensionX = Dimensions1(list);
    int dimensionY = Dimensions2(list);
    String lines = "";
    String stringList = list.toString();
    for(int i = 8; i <= stringList.length() - 18; i++)
    {
        if(stringList.charAt(i) == ',' || stringList.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            //do nothing to get rid of all ,'s or spaces
        }
        else
        {
            lines = lines + stringList.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(lines);
    int offset = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < dimensionX; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < dimensionY; y++)
            {
                maze[x][y] = lines.charAt(offset++);
            }
    }
    System.out.println(maze);
    return maze;
}
```

}

I've printed Dimensions1(lines) and Dimensions2(lines) and both come out to 4. So the dimensions should be 4 by 4, but for some reason it runs out of bounds at 3.

Comment: well, how is the `maze` array declared?

Comment: I just realized that was the problem, but now it's giving me a different one.

My Array is declared:



char[][] mazeArray = new char[Dimensions1(lines)][Dimensions2(lines)];


mazeArray = mazeCreator(lines, mazeArray );

Comment: Post [mcve]. Errors don't lie so lets start by assuming that your array doesn't really have size you believe it has.

Comment: sorry for the illegibility, I'm new to the site. Also it would make more sense if it let me post the whole method too.

Comment: BTW don't post important info only as comment. Use [edit] option to post it directly in your question (don't make people search for it in comments). Especially if it is code since it can't be properly formatted there.

Comment: I edited it.Is that better? I didn't know what to and what not to include.

Comment: I honestly don't see how this example can be useful for future visitors facing similar problem... This exception is caused by fact that you tried to access index which is either negative, or greater than/equal to length of array. You need to step through your code with debugger to see which variables contain values which you believe they shouldn't. Take a look at https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788)